# Using Hokuyo node with multiple lasers

Tags: ros, hokuyo-node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've got two Hokuyo laser scanners, both of which work individually when I run the hokuyo_node and change to the appropriate port. However, I'd like to have them both running at the same time, publishing to two different topics. How do I go about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48878/using-hokuyo-node-with-multiple-lasers/) by [vhwanger](https://answers.ros.org/users/3648/vhwanger/) on ROS Answers with karma: 52 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to remap topic name on at least one of the nodes, and give deffirent names to them. Easiest way is use launch file:

```
<launch>
    <node name="hokuyo0" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node">
        <param name="port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyACM0" />
        <remap from="scan" to="scan0" />
    </node>
    <node name="hokuyo1" pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node">
        <param name="port" type="string" value="/dev/ttyACM1" />
        <remap from="scan" to="scan1" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kost9](https://answers.ros.org/users/20191/kost9/) on 2014-10-07**:
How would one use tf in THIS code to rotate the frame of the second hokuyo by 180', so the messages publihsed to /scan by the second hokuyo are rotated?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just run both an remap the output topic. You might need to set the frame id too.

Here is an excerpt from the launch file that we use:

```
 <rosparam command="load" file="$(find matilda_bringup)/config/sensors.yaml" />

  <!-- Base Laser -->
  <group unless="$(arg disable_base_laser)" >
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="base_hokuyo_node">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="base_laser_link" />
    <param name="min_ang" type="double" value="-2.35619449019234492883" />
    <param name="max_ang" type="double" value="2.35619449019234492883" />
    <param name="skip" type="int" value="0" />
    <param name="intensity" value="false" />
  </node>
  </group>

  <!-- Vertical Laser -->
  <group unless="$(arg disable_vertical_laser)" >
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="vertical_hokuyo_node">
    <remap from="scan" to="vertical_scan" />
    <param name="frame_id" type="string" value="vertical_laser_link" />
    <param name="min_ang" type="double" value="-2.09439510239319549227" />
    <param name="max_ang" type="double" value="2.09439510239319549227" />
    <param name="skip" type="int" value="0" />
    <param name="intensity" value="false" />
  </node>
  </group>
```

The sensors.yaml defines the ports to use, you could also symlink those if you like:

```
base_hokuyo_node/port: /dev/sensors/hokuyo_H0904092
vertical_hokuyo_node/port: /dev/sensors/hokuyo_H0507257
```

To get the names with serials for the Hokuyos you can use the following udev rules (using the getID node from the hokuyo driver package):

```
# Hokuyos
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Hokuyo Data Flex for USB", ATTRS{product}=="URG-Series USB Driver", MODE="0666", GROUP="dialout", PROGRAM=="/etc/ros/run.sh hokuyo_node getID %N q", SYMLINK+="sensors/hokuyo_%c"
```

The run script needs to be available system-wide. It just sources setup.sh and rosruns the program:

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/ros/setup.sh 
rosrun $@
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-11-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cat_in_box](https://answers.ros.org/users/44444/cat_in_box/) on 2019-08-01**:
very helpful!